# Setting nTSecurityDescriptor using IADs* interface

Tags: c++, windows, security, active-directory, acl

I have been trying to modify ACLs any object (AD Object, Directory, etc...) using C++ for a while now.
I tried a bunch of methods and each had their own problems.

I tried using code given here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/example-code-for-setting-an-ace-on-a-directory-object?source=recommendations

But I always get 0x80070539 ERROR_INVALID_SID (The security ID structure is invalid)
I even tried this

```
hr = pObject->Get(_bstr_t("nTSecurityDescriptor"), &varSD);
hr = pObject->Put(CComBSTR("nTSecurityDescriptor"), varSD);
```

Even that did the same thing.

I tried another method where I use a the following methods

```
GetNamedSecurityInfoW
SetEntriesInAclW
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl
IADs::Put(CComBSTR("nTSecurityDescriptor"), sd)
```

But that keeps returning `E_FAIL` at the last statement.

I also tried using `SetSecurityInfo` method but it requires a handle to be passed as argument.
How to get a handle for an Active Directory object like user ?

I've been banging my head over this...
Please help...